# How to make Google's PlacePicker work on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I followed all the steps mentioned in the guide:

- Installed iOS SDKs for GoogleMaps, GooglePlaces, GooglePlacePicker.
- Enabled Places API in google console
- Created an API key and set them in AppDelegate.(I waited for few hours)

[image]

But still I get error:

```
The Places API for iOS is not enabled. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) for how to enable the Google Places API for iOS
```

Comment: Have you done all of the following:
`Click the button below, to get an API key using the Google Cloud Platform Console. You will be asked to (1) pick one or more products, (2) select or create a project, and (3) set up a billing account. Once your API key is created you will be prompted to restrict the key's usage.`
[Get an API key](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/get-api-key#quick-guide)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, in the same link, it says `Reminder: To use the Places SDK for iOS, you must get an API key and you must enable billing. You can enable billing when you get your API key (see the Quick guide) or as a separate process (see Usage Limits). `

Comment: @Bill, I created API, also restricted the usage it to iOS app. I guess, billing account is already created and it's working fine in Android.

Comment: The Place Picker (Android, iOS) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. Read the migration guides to learn more:

Android migration guide
iOS migration guide
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration